# Canvas drawText draws wrong position

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext

I am using;

```
mCanvas.drawText(c.getText(), c.getCordX(), c.getCordY(), a);
```

for draw a text on my canvas object. At Galaxy Nexus text values appears true points but at ASUS transformer tablet, all of them appears false points like images below. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What are the values of c.getCordX(), c.getCordY()

Comment: I add all my text values an ArrayList like this using a model class;
TextPrintModel a = new TextPrintModel(126, 200, "26.02.2013");
values.add(a); 
Then draw all;
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
TextPrintModel c = values.get(i);
mCanvas.drawText(c.getText(), c.getCordX(), c.getCordY(), a);
}

Comment: It would help if you mention how you calculate those values representing the position where the text should be drawn.

Comment: I opened the template on Photoshop and measured bottom and left margin values for texts. It fits perfectly on Nexus but on tablet, works like margin values *= 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Previously I put template background image only drawable-xhdpi folder. Now, I put image, all hdpi,mdpi,ldpi folder, and problem solved.